# Exclude category from shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode

I have the following code and i am trying to exclude a specific category id ex-144

```
function product_count_shortcode( ) {
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'product' );
    return $count_posts->publish;
}
add_shortcode( 'product_count', 'product_count_shortcode' );
```

How can exclude one category?

Comment: You can achieve this using the `'category__not_in' => 6` parameter

Comment: i try it and doesn't work

Comment: You're trying to count posts excluding one category?

Comment: Yeap that's right!

Comment: Updated the code to use `get_term` so as to accommodate custom taxonomies

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer

Comment: How can exclude multiple categories? @tunji-ayoola

Comment: By using [**category__not_in**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) which accepts an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a direct method to achieve this, you should be able to get the category count using [**`get_term`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) then subtract that from the total.

```
function product_count_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $data = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat_id'    => 144,
        'taxonomy'  => 'category'
    ), $atts );

    $category = get_term( $data['cat_id'], $data['taxonomy'] );
    $count = $category->count;
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'product' );
    return (int)$count_posts->publish - (int)$count;
}
add_shortcode( 'product_count', 'product_count_shortcode' );
```

From **iguanarama** answer:

You can also use **[WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)**

```
$myQuery = new WP_Query ([
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'cat' => '-144',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
]);
$count = ($myQuery ? $myQuery->found_posts : 0);
```

Comment: Updated the code to use `get_term` so as to accommodate custom taxonomies

Comment: So i wanna exclude the 144 and 1138 category. The code will be? @tunji-ayoola

Comment: 'cat_id'    => 144, 1138 ?

Answer (score 1):

You could run a new WP_Query using a '-' for categories to exclude:

```
$myQuery = new WP_Query ([
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'cat' => '-144',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
]);
$count = ($myQuery ? $myQuery->found_posts : 0);
```